# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).anotherfunc is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

flip.js effect is working and console.log inside flip:done is also working but "anotherfunc" called inside flip:done is not working. please help.

```
function anotherfunc( ) {
    console.log("its anotherfunc");
}


jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

//it is working here but not inside flip:done
anotherfunc();

$(".card").flip({
    trigger:  'hover',
    speed : 1000
});


$(".card").on('flip:done',function(  ){

  // this is also working
  console.log('from inside flip:done');

  // this is also working
  console.log( $(this) ); 


  // this is saying "is not a function"
  $(this).anotherfunc();

});


});//on laod
```

Comment: that is because `$(this)` is referring to `$(".card").on('flip:done',function(  ){..}` Look into the javascript scope and closure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sould either call it as

```
anotherfunc($(this));
```

or declare it like:

```
(function ($) {
     $.fn.anotherfunc = function () {
           // some code
     }
})(jQuery);
```

Then you can use it like:

```
$(this).anotherfunc();
```

Have a look at this Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/f8w14sbk/

Comment: Thanks it is working by declaring like this. $.fn.anotherfunc = function () {
           // some code
     }

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  anotherfunc is a function, but there is no `jQuery.anotherfunc()` to call on `$(this)`

anotherfunc() is declared on top scope, if you want to pass an object to it do

```
 function anotherfunc(myobject) {
 ....
}
```

and call it for `$(this)`

```
anotherfunc($(this));
```

Make sure to clear out if myobject is allowed to be null

Comment: Thanks it is working by declaring like this. $.fn.anotherfunc = function () {
           // some code
     }

Comment: Great. You should choose and vote then for Ashkan's answer.